# String is not being filled with random chars (C)?

Tags: c, string, random, char

I'm trying to fill a string with characters from the string 'reset\0' but randomized.  For some reason it only gives me one character bacK:

```
#define STR_LEN 6
char *inputString()
{
    char *string[STR_LEN + 1] = {0};
    const char *digits = "reset\0";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < STR_LEN; i++) 
    {
        string[i] = digits[ rand() % 5 + 0 ];
    }

    printf("STRING: %s\n", string);
}
```

prints only one character like 't' or 'e' to the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The variable `string` is an array of *pointers* to characters, not an array of characters like you treat it. That code should have given you plenty of warnings, and if not then you need to enable more warnings.

Comment: Also, if you have a string literal like e.g. `"reset"` it automatically includes the string terminator, by having `"reset\0"` you have *two* terminators and waste a byte.

Comment: You should use the macro `NULL`, not the integer `0`. The latter is now also deprecated in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean making a random permutation of characters, not just using the source string as an alphabet, consider [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). An implementation could be like this:

```
char s[] = "reset";
for (size_t i = strlen(s) - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    size_t j = rand() % (i + 1);
    char t = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = t;
}
printf("%s\n", s);
```

The idea is to go from right to left, and on every step to swap the element at index `i` with an element at random index `j` between `0` and `i`, inclusive.

Comment: Careful. It's very easy to accidentally implement a biased shuffle (e.g, one that cannot generate certain permutations). See [Wikipedia's "Fisher-Yates Shuffle" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for a correct implementation.

Comment: @duskwuff Hmm... It looks close to [The modern algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) from the article. Is it biased? (Besides the fact that `% (i + 1)` creates a small bias in random numbers?)

Comment: This particular implementation appears to be balanced. My point is that minor, accidental alterations may introduce biases, so it's important to verify the results.

Comment: @duskwuff Do you mean, for instance, something like `% i` instead of `% (i + 1)`? Yes, it would create quite some bias.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code

```
#define STR_LEN 5

    char *inputString()
    {
        char string[STR_LEN + 1] = {0};
        const char *digits = "reset";
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < STR_LEN; i++) 
        {
            string[i] = digits[ rand() % 5 + 0 ];
        }

        printf("STRING: %s\n", string);
    }
```

But note that this doesnt do what you want, it print 5 random chars from 'reset' so 'ssere' can be output

Comment: The function is supposed to return something. And it should not be a pointer to a local variable :).